# Weird picture quality using DVI

Tags: windows-xp, display, vga, dvi, lg-monitor

I have a Windows XP (yes, XP) desktop that has a [NVIDIA GeForce 8600GT](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8600.html) graphics card, using an [LG W2042TQ (20 inch widescreen monitor )](http://www.lg.com/ca_en/desktop-monitors/lg-W2042TQ-BF-lcd-monitor). I always had a kinda “weird” display on that computer—not horrible—but everything like the start button and the icons are a bit stretched and wide.

I decided to try if I could have a better display (current resolution is 1280x768). And I saw that behind that computer theres a DVI to VGA converter plugged in the DVI port of the graphics card, and then a VGA cable link the monitor to that converter (weird setup).

I decided to buy a dual link DVI cable, I hooked it up, but I’m getting the exact same display, not even better. I tried changing the resolution to the highest possible (1680x1050) but then the display is even worse (everything is really small--icons, start button, ...), and display quality is kind of bad.

There are 2 DVI ports (side by side) behind the computer, I plugged the DVI cable on the same port the DVI to VGA converter was plugged in. Any solutions on how I could make the display more natural or it just has to be like that?

Comment: So you used your display with a resolution much lower than the native resolution for years. Now you’re confused by the “native” size of on-screen elements. Take a look again: Is the quality really bad? Or is it just different? Are the lines between comments on this page blurred in any way?

Comment: Well everything is soo small... like the icons on the desktop are so "skinny" the start button is really tiny

Comment: You can make those things larger using the control panel. Def. want a full-path of DVI to the monitor, just unplug the VGA cable.

Comment: It’s not “soo small” but almost exactly 76%×73% of the original size. Earlier, you were using your 16:10 monitor with a 16:9 resolution, making everything appear taller than it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

What's the native resolution of your monitor, does your graphics card (and its driver) support this resolution and what is the [screen resolution setting in XP](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/display_change_screen_resolution.mspx?mfr=true), because, from [Display resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution):

> One use of the term "display resolution" applies to fixed-pixel-array displays such as plasma display panels (PDP), liquid-crystal displays (LCD), Digital Light Processing (DLP) projectors, OLED displays, and similar technologies, and is simply the physical number of columns and rows of pixels creating the display (e.g. 1920 × 1080). **A consequence of having a fixed-grid display is that, for multi-format video inputs, all displays need a "scaling engine"** [..] **to match the incoming picture format to the display.**

[Emphasis by me.]

If your monitor has to scale, effects you describe can be the result.

Comment: Native resolution of the screen is 1680x1050. What do you mean by what is the setting in XP ?  My monitor is an LG model Flatron W2042TQ

Comment: @MartinB. https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/display_change_screen_resolution.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thanks but I already know that, I tried it already. Putting it to 1680x1050 makes the display even more worse

Comment: @MartinB. What's the version of your graphics driver? The latest for XP(64) is [v307.83 / February 26, 2013](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).